Trying to copy Teams Channel POST to another Channel and cannot copy hostedContent
I have a Teams Channel where I need to copy the POSTS to another Channel. I am using MS Graph API. Trying to copy the HostedContent (3 embedded img tags) throws an error. Combined, they exceed the 4194304 stream size limit.
Creating the POST without the hosted content, then going back and Updating that POST 3 times with each content doesn't work.
How do I get the HostedContents copied over?
(would be nice if I could also make the new post as the original user)
    $val = '$value'
    $quot = '"'

    $msgbody = $msg.body.content

    $uri = "$url/teams/$srcteamid/channels/$srcchannelid/messages/$($msg.id)/hostedContents"
    $hostedContents = (Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri $uri -Method GET).value
    if ($hostedContents -ne $null) {
        ForEach ($hc in $hostedContents) {
            $uri = "$url/teams/$srcteamid/channels/$srcchannelid/messages/$($msg.id)/hostedContents/$($hc.id)/$val"
            Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri $uri -Method GET -OutputFilePath "$($hc.id).png"
        }

        $HostedContentArray = @()
        $img = 0
        $totsize = 0
        $idx = 1
        While ($idx -lt $hostedContents.Length) {
            $hc = $hostedContents[$idx]
            $contentid = $hc.id
            $imgsize = (Get-Item "$contentid.png").Length
            if ($totsize + $imgsize -le 4194304) {
                $totsize += $imgsize
                $img++
                $txt = "$url/teams/$srcteamid/channels/$srcchannelid/messages/$($msg.id)/hostedContents/$contentid/$val"
                $txt = $txt.replace(".", "\.").replace("/", "\/").replace("$", "\$")
                $patt = "src=$quot$txt$quot"
                $msgbody = $msgbody -replace $patt, "src=$quot../hostedContents/$img/$val$quot"

                $obj = @{
                    "@microsoft.graph.temporaryId" = "$img"
                    contentBytes = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$contentid.png"))
                    contentType = "image/png"
                }
                $HostedContentArray += $obj
            }
            $idx++
        }
    }

    $msg_datetime = [TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($msg.createdDateTime, 'Eastern Standard Time')
    $msg_subject = "ON $msg_datetime, $($msg.from.user.displayName) posted: $($msg.subject)"
    $uri = "$url/teams/$destteamid/channels/$destchannelid/messages"
    $params = @{
        subject = $msg_subject
        body = @{
            contentType = $msg.body.contentType
            content = $msgbody
        }
        importance = $msg.importance
        mentions = $msg.mentions
        from = $msg.from
    }
    if ($HostedContentArray.length -gt 0) {
        $params.hostedContents = $HostedContentArray
    }

    $dest_msg = Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $params

            $msgbody = $dest_msg.body.content
            $img = 0
            $idx = 0
            $HostedContentArray = @()
            $hc = $hostedContents[$idx]
            $contentid = $hc.id
                $img++
                $txt = "$url/teams/$srcteamid/channels/$srcchannelid/messages/$($msg.id)/hostedContents/$contentid/$val"
                $txt = $txt.replace(".", "\.").replace("/", "\/").replace("$", "\$")
                $patt = "src=$quot$txt$quot"
                $msgbody = $msgbody -replace $patt, "src=$quot../hostedContents/$img/$val$quot"

                $obj = @{
                    "@microsoft.graph.temporaryId" = "$img"
                    contentBytes = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$contentid.png"))
                    contentType = "image/png"
                }
                $HostedContentArray += $obj

            $params = @{
                subject = $msg_subject
                body = @{
                    contentType = $msg.body.contentType
                    content = $msgbody
                }
                hostedContents = $HostedContentArray
            }
            $uri = "$url/teams/$destteamid/channels/$destchannelid/messages/$($dest_msg.id)"
            Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri $uri -Method PATCH -Body $params



